# How to obtain the list of authorizations for system:unauthenticated on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

I have enabled anonymous authenticated for Kubernetes, and want to list the permissions for unauthenticated users (`system:unauthenticated`). However, the API server returns the following answer:

```
➜  ~ kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:authenticated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (post selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io))
```

Why do I get an error?

**Version**:

```
➜  ~ kubectl version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.1", GitCommit:"3ddd0f45aa91e2f30c70734b175631bec5b5825a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-05-24T12:17:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.15", GitCommit:"8f1e5bf0b9729a899b8df86249b56e2c74aebc55", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-19T17:23:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.20) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if credentials were expired .The authentication is related to one of the pods which is using a service account that has issues like invalid token.

Try running the below command as given in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials?hl=en_US&_ga=1.254512651.2069297816.1484122139) :

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials [cluster-name]
```

You can also check out this [stackpost](https://serverfault.com/questions/1032367/kubectl-get-nodes-error-you-must-be-logged-in-to-the-server-unauthorized-ho) for more troubleshooting steps.